# Explain why L'Hospital's rule only works for indeterminate forms?

Tags: calculus, limits

In almost every Calculus I course, students are taught L'Hospital's Rule. The explanation given is something along the lines of
$$\text{The limit of the function should "behave" like the limit of the slopes of the function}.$$
Obviously, this statement is definitely vague, but for students with no knowledge of calculus it must suffice for now.

Today a student asked:
Why does the limit of a rational function behave like the slopes only if we have an indeterminate form? Why does the limit of the function not behave like the slopes of the function otherwise?

How would you respond to this question in a way that a first year undergrad could understand?

Comment: I would just take a counterexample.

Comment: Consider $\lim\limits_{x\to 5}\frac{1}{2x}$.  Clearly, this is a continuous function over $(0,\infty)$ and so we may just plug in $5$ to see that the limit is $\frac{1}{10}$.  Now, take the derivatives of both numerator and denominator?  $\lim\limits_{x\to 5}\frac{1}{2x} =^? \lim\limits_{x\to 5}\frac{0}{2} = 0$...

Comment: @JMoravitz Of course the students can make a counterexample for themselves to see why it does not work. That is not the question. The question is $\textit{why}$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Again, not really what I am looking for. This is like saying "Why doesn't it work?" and the response is "Look, here it doesn't work."

Comment: In whichever proof of L'Hopital's you look at, there will be the hypothesis that the expression you are exploring is of an indeterminate form and the hypothesis is used somewhere in the proof.  Examining and understanding the proof will be reason enough "*why*".  Clearly, every valid proof must somewhere use this hypothesis to be correct (*whether tacitly or explicitly*) because otherwise we have counterexamples like the one shown earlier.

Comment: One common proof (of the $0/0$ case) relies on Cauchy's IVT ($\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}$ for some $a,b,c$) and directly uses the fact that both limits go to 0 to turn the right hand side into a simple fraction like $\frac{f(b)}{g(b)}$. You'll find similar arguments in the proof for the other cases. Or are you looking for a more intuitive explanation?

Comment: Not sure how informal/rigorous you want to be, but you could try saying that if you want to approximate $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)/g(x)$ by slopes you are calculating $$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}}{\frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x - c}} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{g(x) - g(c)}$$ instead, so a sufficient requirement is that $f(c) = g(c) = 0$. This should give some intuition to why this is true for indeterminate forms, however if you want to argue necessity the best way is probably by counterexample.

Comment: @Rushy This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Check out this: https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/mb4xl/eli5_lhopitals_rule_how_and_why_does_it_work/

Comment: FYI, the title of your question seems to be stating a property that is not correct, because there are examples of non-indeterminate forms for which an application of L'Hopital's rule does give the correct answer (i.e. it is not true that L'Hopital's rule ONLY works for indeterminate forms). For example, $\frac{3x^2 + x + 1}{x^2 + 2x + 2}$ is NOT indeterminate as $x \rightarrow 0,$ but we still have $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{3x^2 + x + 1}{x^2 + 2x + 2} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} (3x^2 + x + 1)}{\frac{d}{dx} (x^2 + 2x + 2)}.$